# Drop similar text rows of one column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, difflib, sequencematcher

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[9,12,13,14],
                   "text":["Error number 609 at line 10", "Error number 609 at line 22", "Error string 'foo' at line 11", "Error string 'bar' at line 14"]})
```

Output:

```
   id                           text
0   9    Error number 609 at line 10
1  12    Error number 609 at line 22
2  13  Error string 'foo' at line 11
3  14  Error string 'bar' at line 14
```

I want to use `difflib.SequenceMatcher` to remove similarity score lower than `80` rows and only keep one.

```
a = "Error number 609 at line 10"
b = "Error number 609 at line 22"
c = "Error string 'foo' at line 11"
d = "Error string 'bar' at line 14"
print(SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()*100) #92.5925925925926
print(SequenceMatcher(None, b, c).ratio()*100) #60.71428571428571
print(SequenceMatcher(None, c, d).ratio()*100) #86.20689655172413
print(SequenceMatcher(None, a, c).ratio()*100) #64.28571428571429
```

How can I get expected result as follows in Python? You can use `difflib` or other python packages. Thank you.

```
   id                           text
0   9    Error number 609 at line 10
2  13   Error string 'foo' at line 11
```

Comment: yes, drop duplicates by similarity score based on `text` column.

Comment: you have a text column, so you want to compare each pair of them? It's a C_n^2 problem? which element you want to keep? The logic seems unclear

Comment: @Travis Keep first one except other duplicates is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#cross join with filter onl text column
df = df.assign(a=1).merge(df[['text']].assign(a=1), on='a')
#filter out same columns per rows
df = df[df['text_x'] != df['text_y']]
#sort columns per rows
df[['text_x','text_y']] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['text_x','text_y']],axis=1), index=df.index)
#remove duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['text_x','text_y'])
#get similarity
df['r'] = df.apply(lambda x: SequenceMatcher(None, x.text_x, x.text_y).ratio(), axis=1)
#filtering
df = df[df['r'] > 0.8].drop(['a','r'], axis=1)
print (df)
    id                         text_x                         text_y
1    9    Error number 609 at line 10    Error number 609 at line 22
11  13  Error string 'bar' at line 14  Error string 'foo' at line 11
```

Comment: Sorry my real data have more columns, I get many `_x` and `_y` columns after run `df = df.assign(a=1).merge(df.assign(a=1), on='a')`, idea to avoid this from happening?

Comment: @ahbon - One thing - do you need both `text_x` or `texxt_y` or only one of them, not important if `text_x` or `text_y`?

Comment: I get `'text_x', 'sSource_x', 'sDate_x', 'sAbstract_x', 'a', 'text_y',
       'sSource_y', 'sDate_y', 'sAbstract_y'`, but in fact, I think only `'text_x', 'text_y'` are necessary.

Comment: Another question, I can keep either `text_x` or `text_y`, or it's better to keep `text_x`?

Comment: @ahbon - I think `text_x` column is similar `text_y`, so one column should be enough.

Comment: Does this line `df = df[df['r'] > 0.8].drop(['a','r'], axis=1)` means drop columns `a` and `r` and also drop rows which `r`'s values <=  `0.8`?