# Drop similiar rows in dataframe, that have a match of more than 80%

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following problem

I have the following dataframe structure:

| Headline | Text |
| --- | --- |
| First | text 1 |
| Second | text |

"Headline" contains names of news stories, "Text" of the body of the news article.

Some of the Text articles are similar, but not by 100%. I want to drop one of two articles, that have a similarity in their texts over 80% (for every comparison of texts in the dataframe)- which one is not important.

I checked the whole web for a library, but i did not find what i was looking for. Has anyone in the community an idea or a library idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624798/drop-similar-text-rows-of-one-column-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [thefuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz).

```
# import
from thefuzz import fuzz
# use fuzz.ratio() to check for similarity
fuzz.ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
# this outputs 97
# you can set a threshold within a range of 0 to 100, where 100 is an exact match
```